# How do you download and use a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, zip

I'm trying to use a jquery plugin called DataTables but don't know what I need to do with the .zip I got from the site. Is there a way to install it or just a folder in my project I need to include it in?

I realize I'm probably missing something really small and simple right now but I need help.

Comment: for some plugins , can understand confusion if new to using plugins, however this plugin provides plenty of working demos in the download....follow example in demo source and adjust path to js and css files according to where you store them

Answer (score 0):

just embed your plugin after the JQuery file. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tabify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unzip and add to your script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

They teach you how to use it [here](http://www.datatables.net/usage/) but yeah basically you unzip the file and link it as a Javascript `<script>`